# How to reduce time required by docker image to install dependencies?

Tags: deployment, build, dependencies, docker

I have some node docker-containers which basically just look like:

```
# core nodejs just installs node and git on archlinux
FROM core/nodejs

# clones directory into current working dir
RUN git clone https://github.com/bodokaiser/nearby .

# installs all dependencies
RUN npm install

# lets node execute the source code
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

When I now rebuild the image so it collects new updates it downloads all dependencies from npm. This always takes up about 5 minutes.

I am now wondering how I could avoid reinstalling all dependencies.

One idea I had so far is to use `VOLUME` and then share the code repository with the host put this would make it hard to use the image on other hosts.

**Update:**
Another idea I have is to create a volume container which contains a git repo and which is shared with the runtime container. However the repo container must be able to rebuild the other container somehow?

Comment: Why not setup a local docker repository and push your built image there?

Comment: How do you mean this?

Comment: It's possible to run your own docker registry, a local service that operates like the one provided at docker hub. It would be the best place to build and push your images, then they only need to be downloaded at run-time. See (https://github.com/docker/docker-registry)

Comment: This means I build a docker file locally on my development machine and push it to the registry. Then I can pull it from the registry. Doesn't the registry take up a lot resources? I would like to keep everything on a small machine.

Comment: A registry can be as simple as another container running on your machine. Of course I was thinking you had several machines to work with. If all you have is one development machine, follow Chris's advice below and create a base image. That will reduce the amount if downloading you have to do for each image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like what you're after is having a *base image* that builds your dependencies and a *local image* that extends it so that you can build / run quickly.

Something like:

**base/Dockerfile**

```
#core nodejs just installs node and git on archlinux
FROM core/nodejs

# installs all dependencies
RUN npm install
```

Then you could do a:

```
cd base
docker build -t your-image-name-base:your-tag .
```

**local/Dockerfile**

```
FROM your-image-name-base:your-tag

# clones directory into current working dir
RUN git clone https://github.com/bodokaiser/nearby .

# lets node execute the source code
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Then build your local image:

```
cd local
docker build -t your-image-name-local:your-tag .
```

And run it like:

```
docker run your-image-name-local:your-tag
```

Now your local image will build really quickly because it extends your base image, which has already done all of the heavy, dependency-installing, lifting.

As an alternative to doing a git clone inside your container, you could mount your code directory into the docker container so when you made changes to the code on your host, they would be immediately reflected inside the container:

**local/Dockerfile**

```
FROM your-image-name-base:your-tag

# lets node execute the source code
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Then you would run:

```
docker run -v /path/to/your/code:/path/inside/container your-image-name-local:your-tag
```

This will mount the directory inside your container and then execute your `CMD`.

Comment: I also found another approach which may be a good addition to yours: In the nodejs container we could export `node_modules` as volume which is mounted in a data container. This data container could be used across all node builds which would radically decrease download time.